# jdk1.8.0_162 java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java, linux, java-8, linux-mint

I am new in Linux Mint. I install jdk1.8.0_162 in */opt/java/* directory and *.bashrc* file i put `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_162/bin` .

But when I command in terminal `java` it shows `Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object` . Please help me

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java` then `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` - see also [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It works thanks